# How to change draggingFormation for NSBrowser local drag and drop

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsbrowser

I have implemented a view controller with local drag and drop of items from multiple NSBrowser cells onto a cell within the same NSBrowser control.  Pretty much everything is working as I wish, except I would like to find the right place to change the draggingFormation to NSDraggingFormationList, but I can't find an NSDraggingInfo object to make the change.

I have a different view controller that uses an NSOutlineView and putting the above change into the **outlineView:updateDraggingItemsForDrag:** method, does what I want.  I have found references on how to do this for NSOutlineView, NSTableView and NSCollectionView, but not NSBrowser.  Any ideas?